# Access volume in docker build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using docker compose and i have created a volume. I have mulitple containers. I am facing issue to run commands in the docker container. 
I have node js container which have separate frontend and backend folders.  i need to run npm install in both the folders.

```
version: '2'

services:

### Applications Code Container #############################

    applications:
      image: tianon/true
      volumes:
        - ${APPLICATION}:/var/www/html  


    node:
      build:
        context: ./node
      volumes_from:
        - applications
      ports:
        - "4000:30001"
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend
```

This is my docker file for node

```
FROM node:6.10

MAINTAINER JC Gil <sensukho@gmail.com>

ENV TERM=xterm

ADD script.sh /tmp/
RUN chmod 777 /tmp/script.sh

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat-openbsd

WORKDIR /var/www/html/Backend

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/tmp/script.sh"]
```

my workdir is empty as location /var/www/html/Backend is not available while building but available when i conainter is up. So my command npm install do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do, is to `ADD` or `COPY` the `package.json` file to the correct location, `RUN npm install`, then `ADD` or `COPY` the rest of the source into the image. That way, `docker build` will re-run `npm install` only when needed.

It would probably be better to run frontend and backend in separate containers, but if that's not an option, it's completely feasible to run `ADD package.json`-`RUN npm install`-`ADD .` once for each application.

Answer (score 0):

The RUN is an image build step, at build time the volume isn't attached yet. 
I think you have to execute npm install inside CMD.

You can try to add `npm install` inside /tmp/script.sh

Let me know

Comment: Done that, i have frontend, banckend and another folder. So there is npm install in all folder and in frontend bower install. It takes lots of time for container up each time.

Answer (score 0):

As Tomas Lycken Mentioned to copy files and then run npm install. I have separated containers for Frontend and backend. Most important is the node modules for the frontend and backend. Need to create them as volumes in services so that they are available when we up container.

```
version: '2'

services:

### Applications Code Container #############################

    applications:
      image: tianon/true
      volumes:
        - ${APPLICATION}:/var/www/html
        - ${BACKEND}:/var/www/html/Backend
        - ${FRONTEND}:/var/www/html/Frontend  


    apache:
      build:
        context: ./apache2
      volumes_from:
        - applications
      volumes:
        - ${APACHE_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/apache2
        - ./apache2/sites:/etc/apache2/sites-available        
        - /var/www/html/Frontend/node_modules
        - /var/www/html/Frontend/bower_components
        - /var/www/html/Frontend/dist
      ports:
        - "${APACHE_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
        - "${APACHE_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend

    node:
      build:
        context: ./node
      ports:
        - "4000:4000"
      volumes_from:
        - applications  
      volumes:        
        - /var/www/html/Backend/node_modules
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend
```